# How to mock JWT token authentication in unit test?

Tags: django, unit-testing, jwt

I'm writing unit tests in Django where I have to mock JWT token validation. I used the following code but it throws exception.

I suspect the issue is because I'm unable to use decode method because jwt.encode returns a str value which does not have decode method.  But in the sample I came across, jwt.encode returns bytes.

### helper

```
def generate_jwt_token():
    client_secret = getattr(settings, "AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET", None)
    payload = {'user_id': 1}
    token = jwt.encode(payload, client_secret,  algorithm='HS256')
    #Commenting the following line because jwt.encode returns str and str does not
    #have decode method
    #return token.decode('utf-8')
    return token
```

### Unit test

```
  @patch('jwt.decode')
    def test_post_request_with_valid_data_succeeds(self, mock_decode):
        payload1 = {'user_id': 1}
        mock_decode.return_value = payload1
        response = self.client.post(self.url, self.dataset, format="multipart", HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=f'Bearer {self.token}')
```

### Exception

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/unittest/mock.py", line 1325, in patched
    return func(*newargs, **newkeywargs)
  File "/app/apps/datasets/test/test_views.py", line 89, in test_post_request_with_valid_data_succeeds
    response = self.client.post(self.url, self.dataset, format="multipart", HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=f'Bearer {self.token}')
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/test.py", line 296, in post
    response = super().post(
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/test.py", line 210, in post
    return self.generic('POST', path, data, content_type, **extra)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/test.py", line 234, in generic
    return super().generic(
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 473, in generic
    return self.request(**r)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/test.py", line 286, in request
    return super().request(**kwargs)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/test.py", line 238, in request
    request = super().request(**kwargs)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 719, in request
    self.check_exception(response)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 580, in check_exception
    raise exc_value
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py", line 125, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 497, in dispatch
    self.initial(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 414, in initial
    self.perform_authentication(request)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 324, in perform_authentication
    request.user
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/request.py", line 227, in user
    self._authenticate()
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/request.py", line 380, in _authenticate
    user_auth_tuple = authenticator.authenticate(self)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework_simplejwt/authentication.py", line 38, in authenticate
    validated_token = self.get_validated_token(raw_token)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework_simplejwt/authentication.py", line 92, in get_validated_token
    return AuthToken(raw_token)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework_simplejwt/tokens.py", line 42, in __init__
    self.payload = token_backend.decode(token, verify=verify)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework_simplejwt/backends.py", line 136, in decode
    self.get_verifying_key(token),
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework_simplejwt/backends.py", line 99, in get_verifying_key
    return self.jwks_client.get_signing_key_from_jwt(token).key
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jwt/jwks_client.py", line 59, in get_signing_key_from_jwt
    return self.get_signing_key(header.get("kid"))
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jwt/jwks_client.py", line 50, in get_signing_key
    raise PyJWKClientError(
jwt.exceptions.PyJWKClientError: Unable to find a signing key that matches: "None"
```

Comment: The error says, it got the `client_secret` as None